# How do I get the output from Hashmap through asynctask in Android?

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc, hashmap

public class `confirmDeletePopUp` gets and email from a EditText in another class called `removeUser`.  Then it sends that email through `getDetailsAsync` class and calls the DBHelper `getDeleteDetails` class to get the information it needs.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.util.HashMap;

public class confirmDeletePopUp extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvAccountLevel, tvFirstName, tvLastName, tvEmail, tvID;
    String removeEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirm_delete_pop_up);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;

        getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .8), (int) (height * .8));

        tvID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvID);
        tvAccountLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAccountLevel);
        tvFirstName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFirstName);
        tvLastName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLastName);
        tvEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
        final Button confirmDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvConfirmDelete);

        // Send request
        getDetailsAsync detailsAsync = new getDetailsAsync();
        detailsAsync.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);


        confirmDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (tvID.getText().toString().equals("") || tvEmail.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(confirmDeletePopUp.this, "ID & Email are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    confirmDeleteAsync cda = new confirmDeleteAsync();
                    cda.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    // get email to remove from remove user class
    public void fromRemoveUser(String emailToRemove){
        removeEmail = emailToRemove;
    }

    private class getDetailsAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        HashMap<String, String> details = new HashMap<>();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            DBHelper db = new DBHelper();
            details = db.getDeleteDetails(removeEmail);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            setValues(details.get("id"), details.get("accountLevel"),
                    details.get("firstName"), details.get("lastName"),
                    details.get("email"));
        }
    }

    private void setValues (String id, String al, String fn, String ln, String em){
        tvID.setText(id);
        tvAccountLevel.setText(al);
        tvFirstName.setText(fn);
        tvLastName.setText(ln);
        tvEmail.setText(em);
    }
```

My problem is that I cant tell if the DBHelper class is actually retrieving the information from the DB.  This is the code for the DBHelper.  It is supposed to return the Hashmap to the Hashmap variable in the `confirmDeletePopUp` class.  Then set the TextViews to the data found.  But it never returns any data.  Instead i just get the gui popup activity for the class with only the hints in the fields.

```
// get details for deleting user
    public HashMap<String, String> getDeleteDetails (String email){

        HashMap<String, String> detail = new HashMap<>();

        String getDeleteDetails = "SELECT FROM * accounts WHERE email = '" + email + "'";

        try {
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(getDeleteDetails);

            while(rs.next()){
                detail.put("id", rs.getString(1));
                detail.put("accountLevel", rs.getString(2));
                detail.put("firstName", rs.getString(3));
                detail.put("lastName", rs.getString(4));
                detail.put("email", rs.getString(7));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.getStackTrace();
        }

        return detail;
    }
```

Comment: The query in `getDeleteDetails` looks like it might have a SQL injection vulnerability - please use parameter binding if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the type in the `AsyncTask` to return `HashMap` like this:

```
private class getDetailsAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HashMap<String,String>> {



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            DBHelper db = new DBHelper();
            HashMap<String, String> details = new HashMap<>();
            details = db.getDeleteDetails(removeEmail);
            return details;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, String> hashMap) {
            setValues(details.get("id"), details.get("accountLevel"),
                    details.get("firstName"), details.get("lastName"),
                    details.get("email"));
        }
    }
```

You will get the returned details `HashMap` in the `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: i tried, no luck.  But i noticed the email from the removeUser class was not being pass to confirmDeletePopUp.  but its just a simple method.  Not sure why

Comment: Figured it out.  Problem was in the query. Had the asterisk in the wrong place.  This small problem was unforgiving. lol  Thank you for your help.  I did what you said.